# PhpMyAdmin, MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to decrypt varchar(191)?

As when I access MySql from PhpMyAdmin and wanted to change user password from there then it shows varchar(191) beside the password and it is written in some types of Encryption like $2y$10$cp1BPpWTBq8kMWvyOxXjduOPhT68YHEYfj37zDLOLLY10oimc5dQG

Please can someone give me a text with varchar(191) as an example?

Comment: You'd need to change the password using the exact same encryption scheme (algorithm, salt, etc) as the application that set it in the first place in order for that application to be able to use it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, when you see a password stored as varchar(191) and it looks like this: "$2y$10$cp1BPpWTBq8kMWvyOxXjduOPhT68YHEYfj37zDLOLLY10oimc5dQG," it's likely that the password has been hashed and possibly salted using the bcrypt algorithm. This is a common practice for storing passwords securely in databases.

You cannot directly decrypt a bcrypt hash to retrieve the original password. Instead, you would typically compare a user's input (e.g., when they log in) to the stored bcrypt hash by hashing their input with the same algorithm and comparing the resulting hash to the one stored in the database. If they match, the provided password is correct.

Here's an example of how to verify a password using PHP and the password_verify() function:

```
// The stored hash in the database
$storedHash = "$2y$10$cp1BPpWTBq8kMWvyOxXjduOPhT68YHEYfj37zDLOLLY10oimc5dQG";

// User's input password
$userPassword = "user_input_password";

// Verify the password
if (password_verify($userPassword, $storedHash)) {
    echo "Password is correct!";
} else {
    echo "Password is incorrect!";
}
```

This code will verify if the user-provided password matches the stored bcrypt hash. If they match, it means the user has provided the correct password.

It's important to note that bcrypt hashes are one-way functions, meaning they cannot be reversed to reveal the original password. This is a security feature that helps protect user passwords even if the database is compromised.

Comment: This looks like something Chat GPT would write

Comment: Well you might think it as Chat gpt , but I do posses knowledge in MySQL and Php and I have also came across a similar situation , so this is from where i got the answer .